# Electron: Send message from BrowserWindow to Electron app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I have an Electron app which uses a `BrowserWindow` to display a web app.

I want to be able to send a message from the angularjs web app to the Electron app.

I had something like this in mind:

```
//web app
window.notify('message','hello');
```

---

```
//Electron app
window.on('message',function(e){
  console.log(e.text);
};
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ipcMain](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) and [ipcRenderer](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/) for sending messages between the main script and the client script.

Comment: // In renderer process (web page).
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
})
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')

Comment: this is the example given from the link. i cannot require electron in my angular app.

Comment: You of course need to have the Angular app in the scope of the Electron app itself, inside it so you can use the Electron functions.

I'm not so sure if there are other ways around that with getting in scripts into your webapp locally over Electron that handle that, but that is probably way too hacky to be a clean solution.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.