# How to show console.log messages in Electron's BrowserWindow?

Tags: electron

Is there a way to send console.log messages to Electron's  BrowserWindow ?

There is another way around described here: [Electron: Send message from BrowserWindow to Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091014/electron-send-message-from-browserwindow-to-electron-app)

The need behind such an integration is that many applications like [systeminformation](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation) using console.log calls to display information

Typical call is:

```
const si = require('systeminformation');

si.cpu()
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Alternative might be different call to send data to browser window instead of console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what work for me:

In main.js:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
```

and replace

```
console.log(data);
```

with

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', data);
```

Changes in render.js:

```
  ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', (event, data) => {
    document.getElementById('log').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',data + "<br>");
  })
```

In html - create div with id='log'

Answer (score 0):

By enabling Dev tool, you can see the console.log message.

```
win.webContents.openDevTools(); //for debugging

// To send message to web page
win.webContents.send("message", message-content);
```

Comment: That is not really a solution. I need to show messages in webapp, not browser console.

Comment: Console.log is used for debugging. It will not going to display on the web page.
To send the message from main window to browser window use the concept of two way communication. I edited the answer, please check.

Comment: See edited question. Alternative might be to send data directly to browser window instead of console

Comment: @richard, use the second one from answer to send data from main thread to child thread.
`var {ipcRenderer } = require("electron");` to send from child to main thread.